# How to check greater than or less than in Month, Php , Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel

My datas is Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec

```
$currentMonth = Carbon::now()->format('M');

where('month',<,$currentMonth);
```

Not working

Comment: Since these are simple strings and hold no information about order its probably best to check if month is either of a given list, that only contains months "greater" or "lesser" than the month in question.

Comment: _"My datas is Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec"_ - then _that_ is the problem you should fix here first of all. The way you are currently storing your information, is _bad_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the month names in your example are simple strings and hold no information about order per se, its probably best to build a list that only contains months "greater" or "lesser" than the month in question and get models with months in that list.

A possible way could be like so:

```
<?php

function getMonths($month, $direction)
{
    $allMonths = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec',];
    $key = array_search($month, $allMonths);

    if ('before' == $direction) {
        $months = array_slice($allMonths, 0, $key);
    }
    elseif ('after' == $direction) {
        $months = array_slice($allMonths, ($key + 1));
    }
    return $months;
}

$month = 'Aug';
$wantedMonths = getMonths($month, 'after');
$models = Model::whereIn('month', $wantedMonths)->get();
```

This function uses the [`whereIn` query filter](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#basic-where-clauses).

Above code is a concept, you probably need to add some more checks, like test if the month actually exists and make sure no months before Jan and none after Dec are requested, etc.

Maybe there is also some fancy Carbon or date function for this, but this seems like an easy enough solution.

Comment: Superb Bro ....thank for the simple solution bro...